# How do I get the power of each string based on its length?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a string of length 15: `"10101000000010"`. i want to take the exclusive or namely the ^

int s = a[3] ^ a[ 5] ^ a[ 7] ^ a[ 9] ^ a[11] ^ a[13] ^ a[15];

```
//here ^ skips 1 index all the way up until the end of string which is 7.

int t = a[3] ^ a[ 6] ^ a[ 7] ^ a[10] ^ a[11] ^ a[14] ^ a[15];
//here ^ skips 2 index and lets 2 go, and so on...
```

How do I devise an algorithm to do this? I just want the `int` after taking the excluisve or of each index.

So what the question is, I want to what if the length of the String is 20, how do i make it so the procedure above is followed.

That i would be able to replicate the above for any give size of a string

Comment: Are you using ^ to mean to the power of? Assuming your string example intentionally uses only 1 and 0 then your answer is almost certainly going to be 1. Unless you have your first number as 0, then it will be 0

Comment: Can you please clarify what your expected output would be? I don't understand what you think `one` or `two` should end up being.

Comment: yes want the ^ to be used as power i.e 2^3...

Comment: @user3550935 And your string input will only contain "1"s and "0"s?

Comment: So what the question is, I want to what if the length of the String is 15, how do i make it so the procedure above is followed,

   int one = a[3] ^ a[ 5] ^ a[ 7] ^ a[ 9] ^ a[11] ^ a[13]  ^ a[15]

Comment: yes the string will always contain 1's and zeros

Comment: @user3550935 Ok, so the answer is almost certainly going to be 1? (just want to check we're on the same page. Some sample answers for `one` and `two` would be useful)

Comment: @RichardTingle Yes sir, you are right

Comment: `a.length()` gets the length of a string in java

Comment: @user3550935 why does it start at 3 and not 0, 1, or 2? This seems like such a random problem to solve

Comment: Ok let me reedit the entire question and it will give you a clear idea

Answer (score 1):

The following code fulfills your request

```
public static int power(String a) {
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 3; i < a.length(); i += 3) {
        total ^= (int) a.charAt(i);
    }
    return total;
}
```